# Variables defined in __init__ appearing as "not defined" when I use them in other functions

Tags: python

I am currently using classes with functions inside, and in this example, I have defined a class with some variables inside:

```py
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def func(d):
        return a - b - c + d
```

However, whenever I run:

```py
>>> t = Thing(30, 6, 7)
>>> t.func(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    t.func(4)
  File "---", line 7, in func
    print(a - b - c + d)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: a, b, c, d doesn't exist in method context. You already defined them as instance attributes, so you need to reference them using `self`: `self.a - self.b - self.c + self.d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrongly referenced your `a`, `b`, `c` variables in your `func` method.

Try this:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def func(self, d):
        return self.a - self.b - self.c + d
```

Comment: Related explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes